# Geometric interpretation of why some matrices don't have eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I don't understand how to geometrically interpret the formula $Av = \lambda v$
where $A$ is a matrix and $v, \lambda$ are the corresponding eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

For instance, why does the matrix \begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1\\
    -1     & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

not have any eigenvalues? How can I explain this, geometrically without just saying it's not the case because $\lambda^2+1=0$ doesn't have any real solutions?

Comment: $Av$ is simply not a scalar multiple of $v$, that is, $Av$ is not parallel to $v$. Try graphing $Bv$ and $v$ for $B$'s that do have eigenvalues.

Comment: Ok, does this occur because the matrix $A$ rotates any vector $v$ you multiply it with, therefore no eigenvalues can exist for such matrices, because if $A$ rotates $v$ you can never have $Av$ equal to a scalar multiple of $v$. Is that correct?

Comment: novo, you explained better than I ever could. I just said not a scalar multiple. You made it is stronger to rotation. If you're right. I'm quite sleepy right now.

Comment: Yes, this is a correct interpretation of a matrix having no real eigenvalues.

Comment: @NikiDiGiano The rotation comment is correct?

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Jack yes. Most comments did not show properly for me, so I was referring to the comment about rotations.

Comment: @novo you can post as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see an $n$-dimensional vector space as $\mathbb{R}^n$. $Av=\lambda v$ means that the image of $v$ is in the same direction as $v$. You can also interpret it as "$A$ fixes the line spanned by $v$". You can see $\lambda$ as a factor that expresses how $v$ changes.

One can understand geometrically why the matrix you gave has no eigenvalues. In fact, you can clearly see why it doesn't fixe any line. Indeed, here's a thing: given $\theta\in\mathbb R$, the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}

represents the rotation of angle $\theta$. You get your matrix for $\theta=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. You can see geometrically that such a rotation preserves no line.

Comment: That makes sense. What happens if the angle $\theta$  was different? I'm thinking if $\theta = 0$, then we have the trivial case of no rotation. But what if $\theta = \pi$. It would rotate the vector, but they would still lie on the same line and the equality would hold? Does this mean the matrix $A$ has no eigenvalues if it rotates the vector anything but $\theta=\pi$ (aswell as the trivial $\theta = 0, 2\pi$, etc...?

Comment: That's right! With this geometric thinking, the matrix has an eigenvalue (and actually ALL the vectors are eigenvectors) if and only if $\theta=k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. You can also show this using the characteristic polynomial I guess.